# Simplification of the sum $\sum_{k=0}^M x^k\binom{M}{k}\binom{r}{k}?$

Tags: calculus, summation, binomial-coefficients

For any $r\in\mathbb{R}$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$ let 
$$\binom{r}{k}=\frac{r(r-1)(r-2)...(r-k+1)}{k!}$$
be a generalized binomial coefficient.

For $k, M\in\mathbb{N}$ and $r,x\in\mathbb{R}$ is there a way to calculate/simplify the expression 
$$\sum_{k=0}^M x^k\binom{M}{k}\binom{r}{k}?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=0}^M \binom{M}{k}\binom{r}{k}x^k=\, _2F_1(-M,-r;1;x)$$ where appears the [gaussian hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function)